# Knockout.Js Array filter syntax

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Just getting into javascript and knockout.js. I've found a bunch of examples of what I'm trying to accomplish. And I feel like there is a small syntax error I may be overlooking. I'm trying to filter a set already returned (**this.tasks**) from a server via ajax/json. I have that working fine. What I would like to do, is have users be able to switch between complete and incomplete tasks.

I switched the code to just run the foreach loop on tasksFiltered. "this.done" is either true or false.

Task template

```
var taskModel = function(id, title, description, done){
    var self = this;
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.title = ko.observable(title);
    this.description = ko.observable(description);
    this.done = ko.observable(done);

    this.showEdit = ko.observable(false);
    this.titleUpdate = ko.observable(false);
    this.descriptionUpdate = ko.observable(false);
};
```

Page Model

```
var pageModelTasks = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.task_title = ko.observable("");
    this.task_description = ko.observable("");
        this.task_title_focus = ko.observable(true);
    this.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.tasksFiltered = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.tasks, function(Task) {
        return Task.done == true;
      });
    });

   // CRUD functions excluded 
};
```

this doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two minor corrections to your code. First, as @XGreen mentioned, you need to pass the array value, **not** the observableArray instance, as the first parameter of the `arrayFilter` function. Lastly, because `Task.done` is observable, you need to invoke the member to get the value. Here's the modified code:

```
this.tasksFiltered = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.tasks(), function(Task) {
        return Task.done() === true;
    });
});
```

Comment: You're missing the "this" arg into the computed, or use "self.tasks()" instead of "this.tasks()"

Answer (score 1):

The second solution has a problem with the method ko.utils.stringStartsWith.

ko.utils.stringStartsWith missing in release file.

You can use this code:

```
  var stringStartsWith = function (string, startsWith) {          
        string = string || "";
        if (startsWith.length > string.length)
            return false;
        return string.substring(0, startsWith.length) === startsWith;
    };
```

[See Issue Link](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/401)

Answer (score 0):

It might help you

```
if (myList().length > 0) {
    var text= this.filter().toLowerCase();
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(myList(), function (item) {
                if (item.Label.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1 || item.Desc.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1) {
                    return true;
                 }
                 else {
                     return false;
                 }
          });
}
```

Comment: show where this.filter is defined in original poster's code